# Unsupported Operation on AbstractList.add()

Tags: java, list

I got a method

```
foo(list);
```

that get's a

```
List<SomeEntit>
```

as input.

My method foo looks somewhat like the following:

```
public void foo(List<SomeEntity someEntities) {
    someEntities.add(anotherEntity);
}
```

I then get an "javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException" caused by "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null" at "at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)"

Can you tell me why this is happening? I hope that my code example is not too minimal.

Comment: It sounds like your `List` is from some sort of subset, so it's unmodifiable. Can you copy the list, and work off the copy?

Comment: What is the type of "list" ?

Comment: Please show us what `list` is assigned to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some lists are unmodifiable. The operation of adding elements is then "unsupported".

Java collections framework does not have a distinct type for unmodifiable lists or other unmodifiable collections. You never really know if it is allowed to add something. 
All you can do is to specify that the list that is passed must be modifiable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the actual type of the `List` you get as the input does not override the `add` method.

Try converting that list to a list implementation that does, like `ArrayList`:

```
 List<SomeEntity> newList = new ArrayList<>(list);
 foo(newList);
```